# how to check if literal is long type in java?

Tags: java, variables, long-integer, literals

I have to check if value 30508600000 is literal long in Java programming language. When I initialise it in long variable it can't fit since it is too large, unless I put "l" at the end of number. So can this be classified as long literal or not ?

Comment: If you put an L at the end, yes, it's a long literal. That's the point of the final L.

Comment: You *have* already checked. The compiler told you. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to check if it cannot be stored in an `int` and needs be stored in a `long`?

Comment: If you place the L at the end of a number, you are declaring it as a long literal. If you tried to make it an integer literal (without the L), then the compiler may complain that it's too large.

Comment: I want to check if that particular number can be stored as long literal. When I type long x= 30508600000; it can't store it unless I put l at the end. So the conclusion would be that this number is not long literal ?

Comment: You can look at Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE, if you wish to check a value to see if it fits inside the limits of a Long. However, you're going to have to declare it as a larger sized number datatype first. And it may still go outside the range of THAT larger datatype.

Comment: That number you tried to enter (`long x = 30508600000;`), without the L, is implicitly an integer declaration. Which is why it fails prior to being implicitly cast to long.

Answer (score 4):

By default in Java integer literals are `int`, and floating point literals are `double`.

You can change that by adding the correspondent letter to the literal.

The problem you're having when you don't put the L, is that you're trying to create an `int` literal with a value too large for `int` range.